# extjs return ajax response

Tags: ajax, extjs

I need to assign the ajax response to a global variable so that i can use it thoughout my application. The obvious problem is that ajax requests are async thus complicating things.

I have tried to initialize an object before the ajax call, then assigning the response fron inside the success but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Example code

```
var p = {};
loadLang('en');

function loadLang(code) {

     Ext.Ajax.request({
      url : '/LoadLanguage.html',
      method : 'POST',
      params :{'code':code},
      timeout : 250,
      success : function(response, opts) {
        obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        p = obj;
      },
      callback : function(o,s,r)
      {
      }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: *I have tried to initialize an object before the ajax call, then assigning* how did you do that ?? because I have tried your steps, and it works.. edit your question with your current code

Comment: Yes, your question is totally unclear without code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myValue={item:"pie"};

 Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'test.php',
        params: {
            id: 1
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
            window.myValue.response=response; //yay for global scope.
                            console.log(window.myValue);//This has to be here,
                           //else it gets logged before the call gets completed.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Assuming that before the ajax call i do var SomeVal = {};. if i do a console.log(SomeVal) after the ajax call i still have an empty object.

Comment: Defining it as var SomeVal makes it local. SomeVal={};    http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: Whoops that comment is a bit incorrect, since it still gets declared as local to the global scope. See my edited answer

Comment: my goal though is to get response outside the ajax request. I need the data of that call to be used application wide. In JQ i would do  $(p).trigger('loaded') inside success and afterwards something like $(p).bind("'loaded'",function(){}). Unfortunately i'am an EXT noob

Comment: http://mapfish.org/doc/tutorials/extjs.html has a nice explanation on events and listeners. When an action happens, you listen for it in another object, and do stuff as a function.

Comment: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/binding.html has examples of the someObject.on("randomAction",function(),this);